# How to retain Azure platform log data in storage account beyond 365 days?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-monitoring

I am trying to create a diagnostic setting for archiving logs to the storage account. But I could see the retention period option is only provided for 365 days maximum. I want retention period of 500 days. Can I keep retention as forever and handle the deletion part by applying lifecycle at storage account level.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to set the retention policy to 500, but it is possible to keep retention more than 365 days, you can refer to this document.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/diagnostic-settings#create-in-azure-portal

I took a screenshot on this document, so that you can see that clearly.
[image]

You can consider **setting the retention policy to 0** in portal and manually deleting your data from storage using a scheduled job. Setting the retention policy to 0 means you can retain forever.